# How to deploy a grails app with a different context path

Tags: deployment, tomcat, grails

Where in the grails files can I define a different context path for a grails app to run on Tomcat ? (For instance, the project is called *MyApplication*, but I want to reference it as */myapp*) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your deploying to production the easiest way is to just rename the war file to myapp.war. You can also add something like the following to your application.properties to ajust the path you go to in order to access your application when using grails run-app

```
app.context=/myapp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I changed the name and worked just fine.